# Trying to have multiple source ids for xml import

Tags: 7, migrations

In my continued frustration with trying to extend the wordpress_migrate module, I have run into another problem with migrate.

Wordpress uses two unique identifiers in it's categories - nicename and term_id. I don't know why. Nicename is used for matching parent categories, and as the unique identifier in blog posts. However, in custom content types that are exported, they use the term_id in their fields. Here's an example:

```
<wp:category><wp:term_id>41069</wp:term_id><wp:category_nicename><![CDATA[daly]]></wp:category_nicename><wp:category_parent><![CDATA[nt2]]></wp:category_parent><wp:cat_name><![CDATA[Daly]]></wp:cat_name></wp:category>
```

Currently the nicename is being used as the source id, like so:

```
$this->map = new MigrateSQLMap($this->machineName,
      array(
        'wp:category_nicename' => array(
          'type' => 'varchar',
          'length' => 255,
          'not null' => TRUE,
          'description' => 'WordPress category machine name',
        ),
      ),
      MigrateDestinationTerm::getKeySchema()
    );

$fields = array(
      'wp:category_nicename' => 'Unique "machine name" of the category',
      'wp:category_parent' => 'Category parent (nicename?)',
      'wp:cat_name' => 'User-friendly category name',
      'wp:category_description' => 'Description of category',
    );

// Construct the source and destination objects.
    $source_options = array(
      'reader_class' => 'MigrateXMLReader',
      'cache_counts' => TRUE,
    );
    $this->source = new MigrateSourceXML($this->wxrFile, '/rss/channel/category',
      'wp:category_nicename', $fields, $source_options, $this->arguments['namespaces']);
    $this->destination = new MigrateDestinationTerm($this->arguments['category_vocabulary']);
```

However, this is no good for the sourceMigration when I am trying to use the term id. In my head I thought it would logically work like so

```
$this->map = new MigrateSQLMap($this->machineName,
      array(
        'wp:term_id' => array(
          'type' => 'int',
          'not null' => TRUE,
          'description' => 'WordPress category term id',
        ),
        'wp:category_nicename' => array(
          'type' => 'varchar',
          'length' => 255,
          'not null' => TRUE,
          'description' => 'WordPress category machine name',
        ),
      ),
      MigrateDestinationTerm::getKeySchema()
    );

$fields = array(
      'wp:term_id' => 'Unique id of the category',
      'wp:category_nicename' => 'Unique "machine name" of the category',
      'wp:category_parent' => 'Category parent (nicename?)',
      'wp:cat_name' => 'User-friendly category name',
      'wp:category_description' => 'Description of category',
    );

// Construct the source and destination objects.
    $source_options = array(
      'reader_class' => 'MigrateXMLReader',
      'cache_counts' => TRUE,
    );
    $this->source = new MigrateSourceXML($this->wxrFile, '/rss/channel/category',
      'wp:category_nicename', $fields, $source_options, $this->arguments['namespaces']);
    $this->destination = new MigrateDestinationTerm($this->arguments['category_vocabulary']);
```

and then on the mapping, something like:

```
->addMigration('Migration', $source_key = 'wp:term_id');
```

Or something like that. But there doesn't seem to be any way of doing this that I can figure out. When I create the migration with the two columns as above it creates the source1 and source2 columns as I would expect, but I get a series of these errors:

```
Could not save to map table due to NULL value for key field wp:category_nicename
Undefined property: stdClass::$wp:category_nicename File /app/docroot/sites/all/modules/contrib/migrate/includes/migration.inc, line 943(file: /app/docroot/sites/all/modules/contrib/migrate/includes/migration.inc, line 943)
```

Even then, I don't think there's a way to specify which source key to use in addMigration. I can't find an issue that is related that helps me here, trust me I've read them.

Answer (score 1):

The 'Undefined property' during migration errors are usually related wrong passing of unprepared rows, sometimes because of typos in the field name. By default `prepareKey()` is called before `prepareRow()` and you can specify which source key to use by overriding the default behaviour and by defining your own `prepareKey()` method in your class. This is especially needed when your source data doesn't have any primary key and you need to define one.

See this [post](http://Undefined%20property:%20stdClass::$muid%20migrate/includes/migration.inc) explaining that by the following example:

> What the MigrateSQLMap constructor means:
>
> ```
> $this->map = new MigrateSQLMap($this->machineName,
>              array(
>                'muid' => array(
>                  'type' => 'int',
>                  'not null' => true,
>                ),
>              ),
>              MigrateDestinationUser::getKeySchema()
> ```
>
> What this is saying is, take the `muid` value from your source row and
>   use that to populate sourceid1 in the map table. If you source query
>   has a column which is a unique identifier for each row, you should be
>   using the name of that column instead of muid here. If your source
>   data doesn't have a handy primary key and you need to construct one
>   name `muid`, then you would do that in `prepareKey()` instead of
>   prepareRow (NOT by doing it in `prepareRow` and calling that).